# MongoDB as failover database

Tags: mongodb, failover, automatic-failover

If a system is already running SQL Server, is it possible to use a NoSQL database (i,e MongoDb in particular) as the failover database in a SQL Server failover environment? Such that if the primary SQL node fails the secondary node running/hosting MongoDb takes the primary place.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this question is "no". The long answer is anything is possible given enough code and resources.

SQL and MongoDB do not speak the same language, so there would need to be an intermediary that can translate. But this adds another failure mode to the system. It also needs to be complex enough to understand such concepts as "primary". There are connectors out there that will handle either SQL -> MongoDB or MongoDB -> SQL, but I'm not aware of any that are capable of syncing the two in real time. Additionally, it would be up to your application to determine where to query data from and where to write data to. This would be outside something a connector like these will do.